# for-loop with NULL condition, why printf(); execute?

Tags: c, for-loop, null

```
‎#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  for(;NULL;)
    printf("STACK");

  return 0;
}
```

output: STACK
I know NULL have ascii value 0 and it's false, but when i run on turbo c, this program give output "STACK", how it is possible.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear, can you please reword it?

Comment: I don't get any output at all when I compile & run this.  Is this your *actual* code, and are you *actually* getting output from it?

Comment: @jwodder I *think* OP is wondering why there is no output .. which is because the for-loop is never entered (NULL makes the conditional part fail), but that's just my guess, the question isn't clear at all unfortunately

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the OP is wondering. The OP should get help with English because what's written here is too far from grammatical to determine meaning.

Comment: May be the effect of wrong optimization or  I can not believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turbo c compiler is ancient ( 20 years old). The behaviour you are seeing is a bug. The 16 bit application isn't running correctly on your OS ( Win7 ?).

As a workaround you can assign the NULL value to a variable and use that in the condition of the for loop, or even better switch to a newer compiler. Like [wxdev-cpp](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Okay then try this c program on ur c compiler.. my question is why for-loop is true and output is "STACK"

Comment: Because you compile it with turbo c, which doesn't work right.

Comment: gcc or turbo c compiler both give the same output for the given c program..

Comment: What OS? What compiler version? What warning messages ?

Answer (score 4):

"STACK" is never outputted. This is because the conditional part of the `for` statement is always false (assuming `NULL` is `#define`d as `(void *)0`.

Comment: ‎#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
for(;NULL;)
printf("STACK");
return 0;
}

i run this on c compiler and its output is STACK, i mean How for condition is true.

Comment: @nasamind are you saying you *are* getting STACK to print out? That seems unlikely, and also why would you accept this answer which says the opposite (I agree with the answer by the way). It's all very confusing.

Comment: Maybe he has an extra ';' after the `for(;NULL;)` ? Just guessing...

Comment: Yes im getting "STACK" output..